# Como enviar mensagem apenas para um usuário com WebSocket

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, websocket

Tenho uma aplicação de chat em tempo real com *Websocket*, mas no momento ela envia mensagens para o grupo inteiro, gostaria de saber como faço para enviar para um usuário selecionado, no caso quando eu clicar no usuário (de uma lista que aparece ao lado) , ele começar uma conversa com esse devido usuário.

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=chat-websocket', 'root', '');

session_start();
include_once 'config.php';
require_once("classes/BD.class.php");
BD::conn();

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

if ($_SESSION['logado'] != 1) {
    header("Location: login.php");
} else {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8' />
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.chat_wrapper {
    width: 700px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    padding: 10px;
    font: 12px 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.amigos {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
p.nome {
  margin: 0;
}   
.usuarios {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  height: 172px;
}
.box_mensagem {
  width: 500px;
  float: right;
}
.chat_wrapper .message_box {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
}
.chat_wrapper .panel input{
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 5px;
}
.system_msg{color: #BDBDBD;font-style: italic;}
.user_name{font-weight:bold;}
.user_message{color: #88B6E0;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>  
<?php
    echo "<div class='nome'>{$_SESSION['usuario']}</div>";
    $colours     = array(
        '007AFF',
        'FF7000',
        'FF7000',
        '15E25F',
        'CFC700',
        'CFC700',
        'CF1100',
        'CF00BE',
        'F00'
    );
    $user_colour = array_rand($colours);
?>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function notifyMe(nome, mensagem) {
          if (!Notification) {
            alert('Notifications are supported in modern versions of Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Firefox.'); 
            return;
          }

          if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
            Notification.requestPermission();

          var notification = new Notification( nome, {
            icon: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png',
            body: mensagem,
          });

          notification.onclick = function () {
            window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/a/13328397/1269037");      
          };
    }
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
    //create a new WebSocket object.
    var wsUri = "ws://127.0.0.1:9000/pullchat/server.php";
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri); 

    websocket.onopen = function(ev) { // connection is open 
        $('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">Connected!</div>"); //notify user
    }

    $('#send-btn').click(function(){ //use clicks message send button   
        var mymessage = $('#message').val(); //get message text
        var myname = $('.nome').text(); //get user name
        var mensagem = 'mensagem='+mymessage;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : 'sys/teste.php',
            data: 'nome='+myname+'&mensagem='+mymessage,
            success: function(html){}
        });

        /*if(myname == ""){ //empty name?
            alert("Enter your Name please!");
            return;
        }*/
        if(mymessage == ""){ //emtpy message?
            alert("Enter Some message Please!");
            return;
        }

        //prepare json data
        var msg = {
        message: mymessage,
        name: myname,
        color : '<?php
    echo $colours[$user_colour];
?>'
        };
        //convert and send data to server
        websocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));

    });

    //#### Message received from server?
    websocket.onmessage = function(ev) {
        var msg = JSON.parse(ev.data); //PHP sends Json data
        var type = msg.type; //message type
        var umsg = msg.message; //message text
        var uname = msg.name; //user name
        var ucolor = msg.color; //color
        var myname = $('.nome').text(); 
        //var compara = uname.localeCompare(myname);

        if(type == 'usermsg') 
        {
            if(myname != uname){
                notifyMe(uname, umsg);
                $('#message_box').append("<div><span class=\"user_name outro\" nome=\""+uname+"\" style=\"color:#"+ucolor+"\">"+uname+"</span> : <span class=\"user_message\">"+umsg+"</span></div>");
            }else{
                $('#message_box').append("<div><span class=\"user_name\" nome=\""+uname+"\" style=\"color:#"+ucolor+"\">"+uname+"</span> : <span class=\"user_message\">"+umsg+"</span></div>");
            }


        }
        if(type == 'system')
        {
            $('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">"+umsg+"</div>");

        }

        $('#message').val(''); //reset text
    };

    websocket.onerror   = function(ev){$('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_error\">Error Occurred - "+ev.data+"</div>");}; 
    websocket.onclose   = function(ev){$('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">Connection Closed</div>");}; 



});
</script>
<div class="chat_wrapper">
<div class="usuarios">
<?php
    $id_user  = $_SESSION['id_user'];
    $sel_user = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id != ?");
    $sel_user->execute(array(
        $id_user
    ));

    while ($fetch = $sel_user->fetchObject()) {
?>
    <div class="amigos">
    <p class="nome" id="<?php
        echo $fetch->id;
?>"><?php
        echo $fetch->nome;
?></p>
    </div>

<?php
    }
?>
</div>
<div class="box_mensagem">
    <div class="message_box" id="message_box">
        <?php
    $select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mensagem");
    $select->execute();
    while ($ft = $select->fetchObject()) {
?>
                <div><span class="user_name" style="color:#15E25F"><?php
        echo $ft->nome;
?></span> : <span class="user_message"><?php
        echo $ft->msg;
?></span></div>
            <?php
    }
?>


    </div>
    <div class="panel">
    <!--<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" maxlength="10" style="width:20%"  />-->
    <input type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" maxlength="80" style="width:60%" />
    <button id="send-btn">Send</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="response"><a href="logout.php">SAIR</a></div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61002/enviar-mensagem-para-usu%C3%A1rio-espec%C3%ADfico-em-websocket-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - pense em remetente p/ destinatário

2 - Quem remete envia para o socket a mensagem e o destinatário(ex: login).

3 - Todos os "ouvintes" do socket recebe a mensagem, porém você tem que fazer um filtro para verificar se o ouvinte é igual ao destinatário da mensagem, se for mostra a mensagem, se não for retorna sem fazer nada.